# Clojure + Lemur

Tags: hadoop, clojure, amazon-emr, emr, cascalog

I am trying to run some multi step job using lemur+clojure.

I have issue with passing multiple input as argument to clojure+lemur.

As first step for my job I trying to run emr Streaming Job

lemur run ${CONF_DIR}/run-pipeline.clj --master-instance-type ${MASTER_INSTANCE_TYPE} --slave-instance-type ${SLAVE_INSTANCE_TYPE} --num-instances ${NUM_INSTANCES} --ami-version ${AMI_VERSION} --hadoop-version ${HADOOP_VERSION}--bucket ${BUCKET} --jar-src-path ${CONF_DIR}/run-pipeline.clj  --input_folder "${input_folder}"  --output-folder "${output_folder}" --reduce-tasks "${REDUCE_TASKS}" --map-tasks "${MAP_TASKS}"

with single input file my code looks like this

```
(import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.util.StepFactory)
(import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.model.StepConfig)
(import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.util.StreamingStep)


(defn create-step-parsing [eopts]
 (def step (new StreamingStep))
 (.withInputs step (into-array [(str (:input-folder eopts) "/inputs/*")]))
 ...
```

This works fine, but when I try to pass list of input files I get error

lemur run ${CONF_DIR}/run-pipeline.clj --master-instance-type ${MASTER_INSTANCE_TYPE} --slave-instance-type ${SLAVE_INSTANCE_TYPE} --num-instances ${NUM_INSTANCES} --ami-version ${AMI_VERSION} --hadoop-version ${HADOOP_VERSION}--bucket ${BUCKET} --jar-src-path ${CONF_DIR}/run-pipeline.clj  --input_folder "${input_folder1}" --input_folder "${input_folder2}" --input_folder "${input_folder3}" --input_folder "${input_folder}"  --output-folder "${output_folder}" --reduce-tasks "${REDUCE_TASKS}" --map-tasks "${MAP_TASKS}"

```
(defn create-normalizer-step [eopts]
  (def step (new StreamingStep))
  (.withInputs step (to-array (:input-folder eopts)))
```

Here is error I am getting

```
15:44:05 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException
15:44:05    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:2990)
15:44:05    at clojure.lang.Reflector.boxArg(Reflector.java:429)
15:44:05    at clojure.lang.Reflector.boxArgs(Reflector.java:462)
15:44:05    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:57)
15:44:05    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:30)
15:44:05    at run_pipeline17$create_normalizer_step.invoke(run-pipeline.clj:18)
15:44:05    at run_pipeline17$run_pipeline.invoke(run-pipeline.clj:209)
15:44:05    at lemur.core$fire_BANG_.doInvoke(core.clj:711)
15:44:05    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423)
15:44:05    at run_pipeline17$eval178.invoke(run-pipeline.clj:222)
15:44:05    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
15:44:05    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6902)
15:44:05    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:6863)
15:44:05    at clojure.lang.RT$3.invoke(RT.java:305)
15:44:05    at lemur.core$execute_jobdef.invoke(core.clj:742)
15:44:05    at lemur.core$_main$fn__1388.invoke(core.clj:929)
15:44:05    at lemur.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:924)
15:44:05    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
15:44:05    at lemur.core.main(Unknown Source)
```

The code I added is from line 17 to line 19.

Thanks

Comment: Are you still trying to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with the array functions you're using. In the first working example you are using (into-array).

From the docs:

> (into-array aseq)
>
> (into-array type aseq)
>
> Returns an array with components set to the values in aseq. The
>   array's component type is type if provided, or the type of the first
>   value in aseq if present, or Object. All values in aseq must be
>   compatible with the component type. Class objects for the primitive
>   types can be obtained using, e.g., Integer/TYPE.

Because you were creating strings as arguments to the into-array, clojure properly created a "string" array for you.

In your second, broken example, you use (to-array). From the docs:

> (to-array coll)
>
> Returns an array of Objects containing the contents of coll, which can
>   be any Collection.  Maps to java.util.Collection.toArray().

In this instance you created an array of "Object"s. This is not type compatible with "String" as per the AWS Java API for [StreamingStep](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticmapreduce/util/StreamingStep.html#withInputs(java.lang.String...)).

My recommendation is to use  (into-array), with the type specification of String. For example: (into-array String ["hello" "goodby"]). Explicit type specification is nice, in my opinion, for future reading clarify. But as you can see by the docs, (into-array) will guess the typing for you.